# get blob API Call from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, binary-data

I asked the same question at MS qna site too.
In ADF, I tried to call get BLOB() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob
I got this error message:  "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

I'd like to read an image or non structured file and insert it into a varchar(max) column in SQL server. (source: binary to sink:binary in sQL server)
My pipeline is configured as below.

1. linked service:
   base url: https://{account name}.blob.core.windows.net/
   authentication type: anonymouse
   server certificate: disabled
   type: Rest
2. data set
   type :Rest
   relative url: {container name}/xyz.jpeg
3. copy data activity
   request method: get
   x-ms-date: @concat(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'), 'Z')
   x-ms-version: 2018-11-09
   x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
   Authorization: SharedKey {storage name}:CBntp....{SAS key}....LsIHw%3D
   ( I took a key from an SAS connection string....https&sig=CBntp{SAS key}LsIHw%3D)

Is it possible to call the Azure Blob rest API in ADF pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible because **When using Binary dataset in copy activity, you can only copy from Binary dataset to Binary dataset.**

Source dataset property when Source is Binary

[image]

Sink dataset property

[image]

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-binary#copy-activity-properties